# Sencha/Ext -  How manipulate SVG Element included inside an svg file ?!

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

This is my problem....

'mon' function works if i set html property directly with svg code like this:

```
html: '<svg><text id="ID">Example</text></svg>
```

I can manage elements by ID and set an event.

But, if i recall an svg file by tag EMBED or iFRAME like this:

```
html: '<embed src="abc.svg">'
```

the elements included in svg file are hidden!!

If i write for example

```
alert(Ext.get("ID"))
```

with 'ID' refers to an Html Element included in 'abc.svg' file, chrome debugger says:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null (from sencha-debug.js)
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml.*

Can i read elements included in a svg file ?! If so, how ?

Comment: Have you tried including the SVG via an iframe? (I don't know Sencha or extjs, but that ought to work with HTML and thus any libraries using it.)

Comment: Yes i have. But it doesn't work. I tried also to create a child and to append it to the HTML body. Nothing. Svg DOM is hidden. If you want, you can try. Maybe you can do something more. I'm flapping head...

Comment: Did you get the same error? Which error? Changing your SVG to add a namespace (since SVG needs a namespace if saved as SVG), this code works in FF:`<script>
function run (e) {
 alert(e.target.contentDocument.getElementById('ID'));
}
</script>
<iframe onload="run(event);" src="svg-test.svg" />`

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply avoid saving with the 'svg' extension and thus avoid the need for the namespace (and well-formed XML) required by the 'svg' extension.

Comment: Yes i did. Exactly the same error. The problem is with Sencha i think. If i manipulate an svg file without sencha, but only with pure javascript, it works. I don't understand why....

Comment: did u solve ur problem? do u mind sharing with us plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can, the console in this sample will show "cirkel", the type of the embed has to be set, the contents has to be valid SVG and this sample needs the defer because the loading of the SVG takes some time.
Hope this helps
Grtz

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  Ext.onReady(function(){
    var win = new Ext.Window({  
      width  : 300,  
      height : 150,  
      layout : 'fit',
      html: '<embed src="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />'
    });
    win.show();
    var delayedTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask().delay(400, function(){
      console.log(window.document.plugins[0].getSVGDocument().firstChild.childNodes[1].id)
    }, win);

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here The contents of the test.svg file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle id="cirkel" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
  stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: can i get svg from a chart created with extjs like pie chart for example?

Comment: Problem was Sencha. It was a missing feature maybe now solved