# How to use SVGs as an object in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, svg, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to embedded a SVG within the DOM (to be used as an object)?
I have a huge SVG image with small different images on it, and depending on some logic, this small images should be appear or disappear.
Here is some javascript code that can handle this:

```
function changegraphic(type) { 
    document.getElementsByClassName("Type").style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById("image-type"+type).style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi pompeyo i believe sencha touch has svg/canvas support as its documentation link below u should do some workaround to solve ur case.. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.draw.engine.Svg

Comment: Hi i have got an exact link for using svg in sencha hope it helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025161/sencha-ext-how-manipulate-svg-element-included-inside-an-svg-file